# Let me see how good you are :)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

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

Comment: Hi CMinusMinus, and welcome to Puzzling - [this meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/60644) should explain why I expect this puzzle won't go down well here... Providing some context would make this much more enjoyable. Thanks.

Comment: This is, without more information, effectively [OTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), which is known to be information-theoretically secure i.e. uncrackable.

Comment: Except that this is very clearly not random-looking data such as you might get from a one-time pad -- there are lots of approximate repetitions, for instance.

Comment: What _kind_ of [computer-puzzle] is this supposed to be? Brute-forcing a cipher? There's no other obvious thing to do, but it's not even clear that this **is** a cipher. Please make your question clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is closable, but it is poor quality.

Answer (score 4):

Decode Base64:

> TURFd01URXdNREF3TURFd01URXdNVEF4TURBeE1UQXdNREV3TURFd01ERXdNREV3TVRFd01UQXhNREV4TURBd01EQXhNREV4TURFd01UQXhNVEF3TURBeE1EQXhNREF4TURBeE1ERXhNREV3TVRBd01URXdNREF4TURFeE1EQXdNREV3TURFd01ERXdNREV3TVRFd01UQXhNREV4TURBd01ERXdNREV3TURFd01UQXhNREV4TURBd01UQXhNVEF4TURFd01URXdNREF3TVRBd01UQXdNVEF3TVRBeE1UQXhNREV3TVRFd01EQXdNVEF3TVRBd01UQXdNVEF4TVRBeE1ERXdNVEV3TURBd01UQXhNREV4TURBeE1EQXhNREF4TURFd01ERXdNREV3TVRBd01UQXdNVEF3TVRBeE1UQXhNREV3TVRFd01EQXdNREV3TVRFd01UQXhNREV4TURBd01ERXdNREV3TURFd01ERXdNVEV3TVRBeE1ERXhNREF3TURFd01ERXdNREV3TVRBeE1ERXhNREF3TVRBeE1UQXhNREV3TVRFd01EQXdNVEF3TVRBd01UQXdNVEF4TVRBeE1ERXdNVEV3TURBd01UQXhNREV4TURBeE1EQXhNREF4TURBeE1ERXhNREV3TVRBeE1UQXdNREF3TVRBeE1UQXhNREV3TVRFd01EQXdNVEF3TVRBd01UQXdNVEF4TVRBeE1EQXhNVEF3TURBPQ==

Decode Base64:

> MDEwMTEwMDAwMDEwMTEwMTAxMDAxMTAwMDEwMDEwMDEwMDEwMTEwMTAxMDExMDAwMDAxMDExMDEwMTAxMTAwMDAxMDAxMDAxMDAxMDExMDEwMTAwMTEwMDAxMDExMDAwMDEwMDEwMDEwMDEwMTEwMTAxMDExMDAwMDEwMDEwMDEwMTAxMDExMDAwMTAxMTAxMDEwMTEwMDAwMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAxMTAxMDEwMTEwMDAwMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAxMTAxMDEwMTEwMDAwMTAxMDExMDAxMDAxMDAxMDEwMDEwMDEwMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAxMTAxMDEwMTEwMDAwMDEwMTEwMTAxMDExMDAwMDEwMDEwMDEwMDEwMTEwMTAxMDExMDAwMDEwMDEwMDEwMTAxMDExMDAwMTAxMTAxMDEwMTEwMDAwMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAxMTAxMDEwMTEwMDAwMTAxMDExMDAxMDAxMDAxMDAxMDExMDEwMTAxMTAwMDAwMTAxMTAxMDEwMTEwMDAwMTAwMTAwMTAwMTAxMTAxMDAxMTAwMDA=

Decode Base64:

> 01011000001011010100110001001001001011010101100000101101010110000100100100101101010011000101100001001001001011010101100001001001010101100010110101011000010010010010110101011000010010010010110101011000010101100100100101001001010010010010110101011000001011010101100001001001001011010101100001001001010101100010110101011000010010010010110101011000010101100100100100101101010110000010110101011000010010010010110100110000

Decode Binary:

> X-LI-X-XI-LXI-XIV-XI-XI-XVIII-X-XI-XIV-XI-XVI-X-XI-0

Decode Roman Numerals:

> 10-51-10-51-61-14-11-11-18-10-11-14-11-16-10-11-0

Not sure what to do with this...

Comment: Turn it into letters, maybe?

Comment: a = 0, b = 1... Y = 50, Z = 51?

Comment: What about the 61?

Comment: If a=0, b=1,...Y=50, Z=51, 0=53, 9=61, we get this: kZkZ9ollsklolqkla

Comment: Also if you subtract all the numbers (just paste it into Google) you get -300...

Comment: Turn 300 into roman numerals, you get CCC... Cool Calm and Collected.

Comment: yep, I think we got it.

Comment: Yes that's probably it lmao.

Comment: @riskymysteries -- Great teamwork! Nice :):)

Comment: But is it correct? I never thought of CCC.

Comment: @Someone -- No, I don't think it's correct. It was a joke.

Comment: @Someone Is 300 CCC? Yes.

Comment: I know Roman numerals. But I didn't think of the acronym.